# Concat-stream callback does not call

Tags: node.js

Here is code

```
concat = require('concat-stream');
const writable = concat(cb);

let reversedData = ''

function cb(data) {
    reversedData = data.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
    process.stdout.write(reversedData)
}

process.stdin.pipe(writable);
```

It's just taking input but not giving output. What's wrong ?

Edit : This question is same as [Why isn't concat-stream working with process.stdin.pipe()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225158/why-isnt-concat-stream-working-with-process-stdin-pipe) but  answer is not sufficient for me because i don't know how to do as he said in answer. How to close input stream ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't concat-stream working with process.stdin.pipe()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225158/why-isnt-concat-stream-working-with-process-stdin-pipe)

Comment: No i don't know code to close input stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use `concat-stream` with `process.stdin` because `concat-stream` expects the readable stream to end at some point, but `process.stdin` doesn't end.

It would make more sense to just use a normal `Transform` stream:

```js
const { pipeline, Transform } = require('stream');
const { StringDecoder } = require('string_decoder');

const decoder = new StringDecoder();

// Transfrom stream which reverses input
const reverse = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        // Convert input from buffer to string
        chunk = decoder.write(chunk).trim();

        // Reverse string
        chunk = chunk.split('').reverse().join('');

        // Return result
        callback(null, chunk);
    }
});

// Pipe console input into transform stream then into console output
pipeline(process.stdin, reverse, process.stdout, err => {
    throw err;
});
```

- I have used `pipeline()` instead of `.pipe()` so that an error handler can be added to the end in case an error occurs.
- `StringDecoder` is used to convert the buffer received from `process.stdin` to a UTF-8 string.
- `.trim()` is used on the end of `decoder.write(chunk).trim()` in order to remove the newline at the end of the decoded string.